# How to use type-erase in Swift

Tags: swift

Story:

- I have some layouts.
- A layout have a pattern and keys. The layout can make message from these.
- Each patterns have maximum number of keys.

That is my code to expression templates.

```swift
protocol LayoutPattern {
    static var numberOfKeys: Int { get }
    static func make(with keys: [String]) -> String
}

struct Pattern1: LayoutPattern {
    static let numberOfKeys: Int = 1
    static func make(with keys: [String]) -> String {
        return "Pattern 1:" + keys.joined(separator: ",")
    }

    let value1: String
}

struct Pattern2: LayoutPattern {
    static let numberOfKeys: Int = 2
    static func make(with keys: [String]) -> String {
        return "Pattern 2:" + keys.joined(separator: ",")
    }

    let value1: String
    let value2: String
}

protocol LayoutProtocol {
    associatedtype Pattern: LayoutPattern

    var keys: [String] { get }
    func make() -> String
}

struct Layout<T: LayoutPattern>: LayoutProtocol {
    typealias Pattern = T

    let keys: [String]
    init(keys: [String]) {
        assert(keys.count == Pattern.numberOfKeys)
        self.keys = keys
    }
    
    func make() -> String {
        return Pattern.make(with: keys)
    }
}

let t1 = Layout<Pattern1>(keys: ["key1"])
t1.make() // Pattern 1: key1

let t2 = Layout<Pattern2>(keys: ["key1", "key2"])
t2.make() // Pattern 2: Key1,Key2
```

This is valid code.
But I can't write that:

```swift
class MyNote {
    let layout: LayoutProtocol
}
```

I know that I should use a technique called type-erase like AnyPokemon!
I wrote that:

```swift
struct AnyLayout<T: LayoutPattern>: LayoutProtocol {
    typealias Pattern = T
    
    let keys: [String]
    private let _make: () -> String

    init<U: LayoutProtocol>(_ layout: U) where T == U.Pattern {
        self.keys = layout.keys
        self._make = { layout.make() }
    }

    func make() -> String {
        _make()
    }
}

let anyLayout = AnyLayout(Layout<Pattern2>(keys: ["key1", "key2"]))
anyLayout.make() // Pattern 2: Key1,Key2
```

This can be executed. But MyNote class can't still have a property as AnyLayout.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the addition of the associatedtype. It isn't doing any work here. Nothing relies on it. Remove it, and the issue goes away. Don't add associatedtypes until you have a specific requirement for them.

As a rule, if you think you need type-erasure, first ask if your protocol is designed correctly. There are definitely times that type erasers are needed, but they're far rarer than people expect.

If you have an algorithm that relies on `Pattern`, then show that, and we can discuss the way to build that. (There are many techniques, including using multiple protocols.)

It's also worth asking whether Layout needs to be generic here. Do you want `Layout<Pattern1>` to be a different type than `Layout<Pattern2>`? The fact that you're then trying to type-erase it suggests you don't. In that case, there's no reason for the extra generic layers. In your example, Layout isn't really doing any work. Again, you can probably just get rid of it. Let each pattern be its own thing and let Layout be a protocol that binds them with `make()`:

```
protocol Layout {
    func make() -> String
}

struct Pattern1: Layout {
    let key: String
    func make() -> String {
        return "Pattern 1:" + key
    }
}

struct Pattern2: Layout {
    let keys: [String]
    init(key1: String, key2: String) {
        keys = [key1, key2]
    }
    func make() -> String {
        return "Pattern 2:" + keys.joined(separator: ",")
    }
}

let t1 = Pattern1(key: "key1")
t1.make() // Pattern 1: key1

let t2 = Pattern2(key1: "key1", key2: "key2")
t2.make() // Pattern 2: Key1,Key2

class MyNote {
    let layout: Layout
    init(layout: Layout) {
        self.layout = layout
    }
}

let note = MyNote(layout: t1)
```

This lets you make your Pattern initializers much stronger types. The need for an `assert` means you're not letting the types do the work. With the above design, you can't pass the wrong number of keys.